# Show that the finite part of $\frac{1}{x_+}$ is a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I would like to show that the finite part of $\frac{1}{x_+}=\mathbb{1}_{[0,+\infty[}\frac{1}{x}$, noted Fp$\left(\frac{1}{x_+}\right)$ and given by $$\left\langle\text{Fp}\left(\frac{1}{x_+}\right),\varphi\right\rangle=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\varepsilon^\infty\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}dx + \varphi(0)\log(\varepsilon)$$ is a tempered distribution.

I have already shown that the limit exists and its value is $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\varepsilon^\infty\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}dx + \varphi(0)\log(\varepsilon)=-\int_0^\infty\log(x)\varphi'(x)dx$$ but I don't know how to prove that $C\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\langle x \rangle^{2}\varphi'(x)|$ is an upper bound of its absolute value, for some $C>0$.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with $\langle x \rangle$?

Answer (score 2):

You have shown that
$$
\langle \operatorname{fp}\frac{1}{x_+}, \varphi \rangle
= -\int_0^\infty \ln(x) \, \varphi'(x) \, dx
.
$$

Note that the right hand side can be identified as $\langle (\ln x_+)', \varphi \rangle.$ Thus,
$$
\operatorname{fp}\frac{1}{x_+} = (\ln x_+)'
.
$$

Since $\ln x_+$ is a tempered distribution, so is its derivative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\left|\left\langle\text{Fp}\frac{H(x)}x,\varphi\right\rangle\right|&=\left|\int_0^1\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}xdx +\int_1^\infty\frac{\varphi(x)}xdx\right|\\&\le\int_0^1\|\varphi'\|_\infty dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{\|t\mapsto t\varphi(t)\|_\infty}{x^2}dx\\&=\|\varphi'\|_\infty+\|t\mapsto t\varphi(t)\|_\infty.
\end{align}$$